# Diagonalisation of an array of 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I need to diagonalise a very large number of matrices. 
These matrices are by themselves quite small (say a x a where a<=10) but due to
their sheer number, it takes a lot of time to diagonalise them all using a for loop
and the `numpy.linalg.eig` function. So I wanted to make an array of matrices, i.e.,
an array of 2D arrays, but unfortunately, Python seems to consider this to be a 3-dimensional array, gets confused and refuses to do the job. So, is there any way to prevent Python from looking at this array of 2D arrays as a 3D array?

Thanks,

A Python novice

EDIT: To be more clear, I'm not interested in this 3D array *per se*. Since in general, feeding an array to a function seems to be much faster than using a for loop to feed all elements one by one, I just tried to put all matrices which I need to diagonalise in an array.

Comment: Show us some code so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: How does a 3D array differ from an array of 2D arrays? Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: Mathematically, an array of 2-d arrays is, by definition, a 3-d array. What you're asking for is logically inconsistent. What you really want is a way to extract 2-d arrays from a 3-d array; this is trivial in C, but good luck with an answer for python.

Comment: @Thomas Carpenter  It is "trivialler" in Python.  ;-)  ' though I'm not sure this small change in the way we store the 2D arrays would change much with regards to the performance issue which I believe is what the OP is trying to tackle.

Comment: Have you profiled to see how much time is being spent in eig vs everything else?  Phrased differently, does your runtime scale linearly with number of matrixes?

Comment: You could always use multithreading or multiprocessing.

Comment: Yes, runtime scales linearly with the number of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an 3D array like:

```
a = np.random.normal(size=(20,10,10))
```

you can then just loop through all 20 of the 10x10 arrays using:

```
for k in xrange(a.shape[0]):
    b = np.linalg.eig(a[k,:,:])
```

where you would save b in a more sophisticated way. This may be what you are already doing, but you can't apply `np.linalg.eig` to a 3D array and have it calculate along a single axis, so you are stuck with the loop unless there is a formalism for combining all of your arrays into a single 2D array. I doubt however that that would be faster than just looping over the individual 2D arrays.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I want, but the for loop will make it horribly slow. 'Calculating along a single axis' is indeed precisely what I want, but apparently that's not possible.

Comment: @PythonNovice: Since `np.linalg.eig` is semi-computationally intensive, I would guess that the for loop isn't going to have too much overhead compared to the calculation. I did a quick benchmark and at least on my system for the test arrays, the overhead was pretty small, although it might be different for the real data.

Comment: so you're basically saying that there's no way to do it a lot quicker than by just treating the matrices one by one (for general, say, random matrices)?